# Algorithm for expressing reordering, as minimum number of object moves

Tags: algorithm, synchronization

This problem arises in synchronization of arrays (ordered sets) of objects.

Specifically, consider an array of items, synchronized to another computer.  The user moves one or more objects, thus reordering the array, behind my back.  When my program wakes up, I see the new order, and I know the old order.  I must transmit the changes to the other computer, reproducing the new order there.  Here's an example:

```
index         0    1    2
old order     A    B    C
new order     C    A    B
```

Define a *move* as moving a given object to a given new index.  The problem is to express the reordering by transmitting a minimum number of *moves* across a communication link, such that the other end can *infer* the remaining moves by taking the unmoved objects in the old order and moving them into as-yet unused indexes in the new order, starting with the lowest index and going up.  This method of transmission would be very efficient in cases where a small number of objects are moved within a large array, displacing a large number of objects.

Hang on.  Let's continue the example.  We have

```
CANDIDATE 1
Move A to index 1
Move B to index 2
Infer moving C to index 0  (the only place it can go)
```

Note that the first two *moves* are required to be transmitted.  If we don't transmit *Move B to index 2*, B will be inferred to index 0, and we'll end up with  B A C, which is wrong.  We need to transmit two moves.  Let's see if we can do better…

```
CANDIDATE 2
Move C to index 0
Infer moving A to index 1  (the first available index)
Infer moving B to index 2  (the next available index)
```

In this case, we get the correct answer, C A B, transmitting only one move, *Move C to index 0*.  Candidate 2 is therefore better than Candidate 1.  There are four more candidates, but since it's obvious that at least one move is needed to do anything, we can stop now and declare Candidate 2 to be the winner.

I think I can do this by brute forcibly trying all possible candidates, but for an array of N items there are N! (N factorial) possible candidates, and even if I am smart enough to truncate unnecessary searches as in the example, things might still get pretty costly in a typical array which may contain hundreds of objects.

The solution of just transmitting the whole order is not acceptable, because, for compatibility, I need to emulate the transmissions of another program.

If someone could just write down the answer that would be great, but advice to *go read Chapter N of computer science textbook XXX* would be quite acceptable.  I don't know those books because, I'm, hey, *only* an electrical engineer.

Thanks!

Jerry Krinock

Comment: Define a "move" more precisely. When to move a object from location i to location j, what happens to object at j? Does everything at or after j shifts right by one?

Comment: @ElKamina OP explains it already; all the objects who were not explicitly moved are re-located in their original order to the spots that were not targets of any explicit moves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is reducible to [Longest common subsequence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem), just find this common subsequence and transmit the moves that are not belonging to it. There is no prove of optimality, just my intuition, so I might be wrong. Even if I'm wrong, that may be a good starting point to some more fancy algorithm.

Comment: I got sidetracked onto another issue so I haven't tested this yet, but did some thinking scratching on paper and agree that this makes sense.  At first it kind of threw me that the "longest common subsequence" need not be contiguous, but now I understand that doesn't matter.  We're eliminating the commonality in the two orderings, and indeed this would be quite analogous to file diffing, which is what LCS algorithm is used for.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Information theory based approach**

First, have a bit series such that 0 corresponds to 'regular order' and 11 corresponds to 'irregular entry'. Whenever there in irregular entry also add the original location of the entry that is next.

Eg. Assume original order of ABCDE for the following cases

ABDEC: 001 **3** 01 **2**

BCDEA: 1 **1** 0001 **0**

Now, if the probability of making a 'move' is p, this method requires roughly n + n*p*log(n) bits.

Note that if p is small the number of 0s is going to be high. You can further compress the result to:

n*(p*log(1/p) + (1-p)*log(1/(1-p))) + n*p*log(n)  bits

Comment: Thank you, but I can't follow the example.  I see that, in the first case, the "AB" creates "00".  If you meant that "1" corresponds to 'irregular entry', then I understand the 1 3.  But then I get lost again.  I think that the answer should be 001 3 1 4 1 2, because the last three symbols "DEC" are all irregular.  But, more importantly, I have no idea what I would do with those sequences and how they'd relate to minimizing the information to be transmitted.  Probably I didn't learn enough information theory.  Thanks, anyhow.

Comment: in DEC 'DE' is still regular. That is why there is a 0. Coming to information reduction, encoding each letter takes logn bits and if you want to transmit the whole string, it takes nlogn bits. If the error rate (in your case 'Move's) is constant, all you can do is reduce logn part to something smaller, which is what I am trying to do here. If you assume constant number of 'Move's (irrespective of size of string) you can do better and probably encode the whole string in constant space.